# Multiple Data Under One Heading with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a scraper with the following two functions at towards the bottom of the crawling process.

```
def parse_summary(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(hxs.select("//div[@class='PrimaryContent']").extract()[0])
    text = soup.get_text()
    item['main_summary'] = text

    summary_links = hxs.select("//ul[@class='module_leftnav']/li/a/@href").extract()
    chap_summary_links = [urljoin(response.url, link) for link in summary_links]

    for link in chap_summary_links:
        print 'yielding request to chapter summary.'
        yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_chap_summary_link, meta={'item': item})


def parse_chap_summary_link(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['chapter_summaries'] = hxs.select("//h1/text()").extract()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(hxs.select("//div[@class='PrimaryContent']").extract()[0])
    text = soup.get_text()
    item['chapter_summaries'] += [text]
    yield item
```

At the bottom of `parse_summary`, I yield requests to `parse_chap_summary_link` in order to extract data from a chapter summary page. This works, but the problem is that the output is giving me:

```
{item 1, [chapter 1 summary]}
{item 1, [chapter 2 summary]}
```

But I want:

```
{item 1, [Chapter 1 summary, Chapter 2 Summary]}
{item 2, [Chapter 1 summary, Chapter 2 Summary, Chapter 3 etc etc]}
```

How can I get all the chapter summary info into one heading, rather than creating a new item for each chapter summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to perform each request after another. For example

```
def parse_summary(self, response):
    # ...

    links = [urljoin(response.url, link) for link in summary_links]
    return self._dispatch_summary_request(item, links)

def parse_chap_summary_link(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']

    # ... collect summary into the item field

    return self._dispatch_summary_request(item, response.meta['summary_links'])

def _dispatch_summary_request(self, item, links):
    try:
        next_link = links.pop()
    except IndexError:
        # no links left
        return item
    else:
        # TODO: it might happen that one request fails and to not lose the item
        # the request must have an errback callback to handle the failure and
        # resume the next summary request.
        return Request(next_link, meta={'item': item, 'summary_links': links},
                       callback=self.parse_chap_summary_link)
```

Another option is to use the [inline_requests](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests) decorator:

```
@inline_requests
def parse_summary(self, response):
    # ...
    for link in chap_summary_links:
        try:
            response = yield Request(link)
        except Exception:
            # TODO: handle the error, log or something
            pass
        else:
            # extract the summary as in parse_chap_summary_link ...
            item['chapter_summaries'] += [text]

    # Must use yield at the end as this callback is a generator
    # due the previous yield statements.
    yield item
```

Comment: Hi Rho, thanks for your answer. I have tried the first method, which mostly works, although it only captures the text of the first summary link, not the others if they exist. Could you give me some tips on this?

Comment: Ah, just got it. I needed to initialise `item['chapter_summaries']` to an empty list in `parse_summary`.